# Is it possible to run Hadoop queries once Hive is installed?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm new to Hadoop, but I have been trying to create a single-node cluster for a college project. Just to set a context to my question, my projetct goal is to perform mapreduce jobs into the same data but while using different Hadoop-based software, these being Hive and Pig. 
So, I wanted to know if, once I have a Hadoop running with Hive installed, how can I differ its commands? Since Hive is set, the node is its?

Comment: Did you set up your hive-site.xml ?

Comment: @Junayy I haven't doen it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, regular MapReduce jobs can still be run against the Hadoop cluster after Hive has been installed. Hive itself just converts the HiveQL queries into MapReduce jobs that it submits.

Comment: @gabrielacschimidt If you mean telling the difference between the jobs, by default the Hive MapReduce jobs have names based on the queries that they're running.